# Case insensitive matching in Java switch-case statement

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I was wondering if there is a way to perform case insensitive match in java switch case statement. the default implementation is **case sensitive**. Please see the example below.

```
public class SwitchCaseTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        switch ("UPPER") {
            case  "upper" :
                System.out.println("true");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("false");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So above statement returns `false` as output. And i am trying make it work for **case-insensitive** match like `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` would do. I tried to convert both the string literal to lower case and then compare. but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want to do that: just make sure the input data is in all lowercase, and use lowercase cases...

```
switch ("UPPER".toLowerCase()) {
case  "upper" :

....
```

#### Localization issues

Also, the ages old issue of localization strikes again, and plagues this thing too... For example, in the Turkish Locale, the uppercase counterpart of `i` is not `I`, but `İ`... And in return, the `I` is not transformed to `i`, but a "dotless i": `ı`. Don't underestimate this, it can be **[a deadly mistake](http://gizmodo.com/382026/a-cellphones-missing-dot-kills-two-people-puts-three-more-in-jail)**...

Comment: thanks. i had tried this earlier and works. but i want to be more sure by converting both key and case to lower and then do match.. can this be done ?

Comment: @PunithRaj No, you can't have something like `case "upper".toLowerCase()` -- you have to do it by hand...

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? Why did you downvote all the answers to this question?

Answer (score 3):

You try making everything uppercase or lowercase

```
String str = "something".toUpperCase();
switch(str){
case "UPPER":
}
```

or

```
String str = "something".toLowerCase();
swtich(str){
case "lower":
}
```

or even better use enum (note this is only possible from Java 7)

```
enum YourCases {UPPER1, UPPER2} // cases.
YourCases c = YourCases.UPPER1; // you will probably get this value from somewhere
switch(c){
case YourCases.UPPER1: ....
break;
case YourCases.UPPER2: ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a switch statement you must use "break;" for it to exit the statement, so simply use two cases, one without a break.

switch(choice)

```
        {

            case 'I':

            case 'i':

                //Insert a name

                System.out.print("Insert a name to add to the list: ");

                input.nextLine();

                name = input.nextLine();

                nameList.insert(name);

                System.out.println();

                break;
```

This way, if either "I" or "i" are entered, both cases will have the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
switch ("UPPER".toUpperCase()) {
    case  "UPPER" :
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to use the case expression to verify if it is lowercase or uppercase, I recommend that you use the following:

```
String value = String.valueOf(userChoice).toUpperCase();
```

This helps to make the conversion of lowercase to uppercase before doing the evaluation in the switch case.